# Performance issues with different types of uniform buffer

Tags: opengl

I've tested different buffer layouts, because I'm confused about some performance issues. That are my test buffer (OpenGL 4.1, GLSL 410, GT 750M, MacBook Pro):

**Test #1: Using fixed struct buffer with unused variables inside**

```
struct SPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    vec4 m_UnusedButPlaned1;
    vec4 m_SometimesInUse2;
    vec4 m_UnusedButPlaned3;
    vec4 m_Used4;
    mat4 m_Used5;
    mat4 m_Used6;
};

layout(row_major, std140) uniform UPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    SPerFrameUniformBufferVS m_PerFrameUniformBufferVS;
};
```

**Test #2: Same buffer without unused variables**

```
struct SPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    vec4 m_Used4;
    mat4 m_Used5;
    mat4 m_Used6;
};

layout(row_major, std140) uniform UPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    SPerFrameUniformBufferVS m_PerFrameUniformBufferVS;
};
```

**Test #3: Using fixed buffer with unused variables inside**

```
layout(row_major, std140) uniform UPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    vec4 m_UnusedButPlaned1VS;
    vec4 m_SometimesInUse2VS;
    vec4 m_UnusedButPlaned3VS;
    vec4 m_Used4VS;
    mat4 m_Used5VS;
    mat4 m_Used6VS;
};
```

**Test #4: Same buffer without unused variables**

```
layout(row_major, std140) uniform UPerFrameUniformBufferVS
{
    vec4 m_Used4VS;
    mat4 m_Used5VS;
    mat4 m_Used6VS;
};
```

*In my case i've the following performance results:*

- Test #1: 40 FPS
- Test #2: 55 FPS
- Test #3: 46 FPS
- Test #4: >60 FPS

My application do 1558 draw and 2341 glGetUniformBlockIndex calls. glGetUniformBlockIndex seems to be the bottle neck, because it is much higher in Test #1 and Test #3.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense, if `glGetUniformBlockIndex (...)` is the bottleneck, then changing the data structure is not going to do anything. In the worst possible scenario, that is a string comparison against every named block in a GLSL program - its runtime does not change unless you add more blocks to search or change the name. More than likely what you're seeing is that API call is the slowest thing on the CPU-side and the actual bottleneck is GPU-side; OpenGL timer queries were invented for this reason.

Comment: I know, but the OpenGL Profiler statistics for glGetUniformBlockIndex () are: Test #1 - 5.50 Avg. Time, 56.45% GL Time, 36.26% App time; Test #4 - 1.88 Avg. Time, 30.56% GL Time, 16.40% App time. I think the problem is maybe a driver check against missing/unused variables? Or is it the size of the buffer in general?

Comment: It can't really do that for uniform blocks, it's not allowed to eliminate unused variables because the memory layout in GLSL needs to match the layout on the CPU. My best guess as for the difference in performance is that the larger data structure crosses a cache boundary, but it is really rare for that to have a measurable performance impact in a vertex shader these days; in a fragment or geometry shader it is understandable, but very little software is vertex bound anymore. In any event, `glGetUniformBlockIndex (...)` only needs to be called once, calling it repeatedly will hurt performance.

Comment: I forgot to say that I changed the data structure on both sides (CPU and GPU as well) for the tests. But you are right. I have to reduce the number of `glGetUniformBlockIndex()` calls. Nevertheless the results are strange.